# Weird Spacing Between Text Input and Keyboard Android react native

Tags: react-native

Please, can anybody help me, I'm seeing this issue on Android and have no idea why it's happening? I tried KeyboardAvoidingView, but still, nothing is happening, that's when I tried to use behavior="padding" instead of height and setting it to some number or zero, but that doesn't help either (an even bigger gap is created). Did anyone have a similar problem?

This is my code:

```
let content = (
<KeyboardAvoidingView
  style={{
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.bodyColor,
  }}
  behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'padding'}
  keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 120 : -120}>
  <View style={{flex: 8}}>
    <SectionList
      bounces={true}
      inverted
      stickySectionHeadersEnabled={true}
      contentContainerStyle={{}}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
      sections={props.messages[0].data}
      extraData={props.messages.has_more}
      onEndReached={() => {
        props.loadMoreData(props.route.params.channel, props.cursor);
      }}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
      keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
      renderSectionFooter={renderSectionFooter}
      renderItem={renderItem}
    />
  </View>
  <View
    style={{
      flex: 1,
      flexShrink: 1,
      backgroundColor: theme.bodyColor,
      width: width,
      borderTopWidth: 1,
      borderTopColor: theme.footerBorderColor,
    }}>
    <View
      style={{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        borderRadius: 30,
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#AEAEAE',
        margin: 20,
        marginTop: 10,
        marginBottom: 10,
      }}>
      <TextInput
        style={{
          padding: 15,
          color: '#4A4A4A',
          flex: 8,
          minHeight: 45,
        }}
        value={props.newMessage}
        onChangeText={(newText) => props.setNewMessage(newText)}
        placeholderTextColor={'#9A9A9A'}
        placeholder={'Type Your Message'}
        color={theme.primaryTextColor}
      />
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: 'flex-end',
          marginRight: 15,
        }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={props.sendingMessage ? 1 : 0.7}
          disabled={props.sendingMessage}
          onPress={() => {
            props.sendMessage(props.route.params.channel, props.newMessage);
          }}>
          <SendIcon size={24} active={theme.fab.fabBackgroundColor} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

);

Image of the problem:

[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Kzrs.png)

Comment: Place your code in any online code compiler like snack/codesandbox

Answer (score 2):

I removed the property android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" from AndroidManifest and the padding space was avoided.

Answer (score 0):

you can use behavior `Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "position"`